# jQuery changing data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have three simple buttons.

```
<div class="enter-btn">Enter</div>

<div class="all-btn">All</div>


<div class="category-all">
    <div class="back-btn" data-action="">Back</div>
</div>
```

When you click on either `Enter` or `All`, it adds a `data-action` value to the `Back` button.

```
$(".enter-btn").bind("click", function() {
    $(".back-btn").attr("data-action", "search-home");
});

$(".all-btn").bind("click", function() {
    $(".back-btn").attr("data-action", "category-home");
});

$(".back-btn").bind("click", function() {
   alert($(this).data("action")); 
});
```

But if you click `Enter` first, then `All` the value on the `Back` buttons seems to hold the first value and not get the new one.

I've added a simple jsfiddle to show my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/uCyJx/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For changing the data attributes use the data function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/:

```
$(".back-btn").data("action", "search-home");
```

Comment: Figured it was something simple I was overlooking. Thanks! Will accept as soon as it lets me